# Flutter IOS build archive not working while trying to get it on Test flight

Tags: ios, flutter

I am developing a flutter project. While I run my application on an IOS device it's working perfectly. I want to release my application in test flight for testing, when I tried to archive (Product->Archive) am got the below error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kServiceInfoFileType", referenced from:
      -[FIRDynamicLinks configureDynamicLinks:] in FIRDynamicLinks.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponentType", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRDynamicLinks.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDependency", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRDynamicLinks.o
  "_FIRFirebaseVersion", referenced from:
      -[FIRDynamicLinks checkForPendingDynamicLink] in FIRDynamicLinks.o
      -[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinkInternalFromUniversalLinkURL:completion:] in FIRDynamicLinks.o
      -[FIRDynamicLinks resolveShortLink:completion:] in FIRDynamicLinks.o
      +[FIRDynamicLinks genericDiagnosticInformation] in FIRDynamicLinks.o
  "_FIRLogError", referenced from:
      _FDLLog in FDLLogging.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRDynamicLinks.o
  "_FIRLogNotice", referenced from:
      _FDLLog in FDLLogging.o
  "_kServiceInfoFileName", referenced from:
      -[FIRDynamicLinks configureDynamicLinks:] in FIRDynamicLinks.o
  "_FIRLogInfo", referenced from:
      _FDLLog in FDLLogging.o
  "_FIRLogWarning", referenced from:
      _FDLLog in FDLLogging.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRDynamicLinkComponentsKeyProvider.o
      objc-class-ref in FIRDynamicLinks.o
  "_FIRLogDebug", referenced from:
      _FDLLog in FDLLogging.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using Xcode version 12.5.[image: Error Image]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Don't post errors as screenshot. Paste as text instead.

Answer (score 0):

you highlight a warning.... warnings should not be the problem.

try this.

1. in flutter project dir -> `flutter clean`
2. in ios dir -> delete `Podfile.lock`
3. run -> `pod repo update`
4. check in xcode your app account settings (provisioning files, certificates etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Raegtime. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

your third party lib not support armv7 arc

try this:

1. in ios dir, open runner.xcworkspace
2. project-> runner `build settings` find Architectures, set the value to arm64
3. targets-> runner `build settings` find Architectures, set the value to arm64
4. run `pod install`

this works for me, but this option will only support the devices release after iPhone 5s, and can not support old device

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I can only open Runner.xcodeproj, unable to open runner.xcworkspace. How to do it?

Comment: can you find witch marked in the image attached in the Xcode?

Comment: Please see the image that I updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You got `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7`, which might be because you don't have `armv7` in your Architecture defined. Try this:
[image]